# Select distinct takes long time for large database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE notes (noteId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, note, note_length, count, unique(note) on conflict abort)
```

It contains 3 million rows.

I then execute the following command:

```
def getDistintNoteCountList(note_length):
   with sqlite3.connect(r'./note_database') as connection:
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute('select distinct count from notes where note_length = ?', [note_length])
      return [i[0] for i in cursor]
```

However, it takes 30 seconds for this function to execute, where the returned list has a size of around 20. Is this reasonable considering that I have 3 million records or have I done something wrong?

Thanks,

Barry

**EDIT**

Added:

```
cursor.execute("create index countIndex on notes (count)")
cursor.commit()
```

And reloaded the data into the database. It still seems to be just as slow.

Comment: Did you try adding an index on count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the query has a where clause involving note_length, and requires the count field, the optimal index would be (note_length,count) in that order. This is a covering index btw, but I'm not sure sqlite is able to exploit it in this situation.

sqlite query planning is explained [in this page](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)

Answer (score 2):

The solution passes by optimisation.

Make a [index](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on the `count` and it will be pretty faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create complex index not only on `count` column, but both on `count` and `note_length` columns.

Answer (score 0):

In order for DISTINCT to do what it does, it has to execute a sort so that it can remove duplicates. Depending on the underlying table/query resultset size, and what (if any) indexes are available, this can often be an expensive step.

I'm not an SQLlite expert, but if that is a nested query in a loop that executes many times, it's going to sting. Also, is that SELECT DISTINCT COUNT entirely right? Surely COUNT only returns one value and is, by definition, distinct?

Both of these points might be tosh. I'd definitely ask myself if my tables were indexed appropriately, though. And whether the DISTINCT was necessary at all.

Comment: `count` is the name of one of the columns in the OP (you may need to scroll to the right to see it).

Comment: Yeah, didn't spot that. Mind you, calling a column by the same name as an integral function isn't entirely good practice, so my point would remain valid if it were COUNT and not 'count'. Plus the points about looped DISTINCT and indexing remain valid.